# External scripts stop working with <Link> in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, gatsby

I am having some issues with an external script when using `<Link to="/">`.

The script is loaded into the main layout `index.js` as

```
componentDidMount () {
  const tripadvisorLeft = document.createElement("script");
  tripadvisorLeft.src = "https://www.jscache.com/wejs?wtype=selfserveprop&uniq=789&locationId=10467767&lang=en_NZ&rating=true&nreviews=0&writereviewlink=true&popIdx=true&iswide=true&border=false&display_version=2";
  tripadvisorLeft.async = true;
  document.body.appendChild(tripadvisorLeft);
}
```

and then used within a `component` as **JSX**

```
<div id="TA_selfserveprop789" className="TA_selfserveprop">
   <ul id="3LacWzULQY9" className="TA_links 2JjshLk6wRNW">
      <li id="odY7zRWG5" className="QzealNl"></li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

This works fine when the browser is reloaded or URL is linked to is a normal `<a href` anchor. Yet, when using `<Link>` the script is present in the page source but doesn't load the data.

I kept the script loading from within `index.js` as when linking to the page I found the script was being added to the page source multiple times. It also doesn't appear to change the issue and performance is the same either way.

[image: example]

Comment: May be you can start by doing console.log() inside componentDidMount() and componentWillUnmount() to see if the component is actually being remounted multiple times. If it is, then that is the main issue you want to solve.

Comment: Thank you @Jackyef. I checked this when I moved the `componentDidMount()` from the component to the layout - only mounted the once - problems seems that whilst it's mounted, it's not being called within other pages when using ` react router` or in my case `gatsby-link`. I have not put the script through `componentWillUnmount()`. Is there a reason why I should be? Thanks again.

Comment: Can you put together the snippet using codesandbox.io so it will be easier to investigate?

Comment: Just going to start a live chat and send you details. Cheers

Comment: https://github.com/discovr-bookings/blacksands here is a git repository. Might be easier for you to see from here - import if you need.

Comment: Maybe you could provide more code related like how you load the data.

Comment: That is it - the widget is supplied by TripAdvisor -  https://www.tripadvisor.com/Widgets-g60982-d87016-Hilton_Hawaiian_Village_Waikiki_Beach_Resort-Honolulu_Oahu_Hawaii.html#w-selfserveprop

Comment: It should just be a drop-in - the issue is that the script loads via a browser refresh but not via `react-router`. You can see live here https://confident-mayer-6cad5b.netlify.com/reviews/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `require()` and remove script injection from `ComponentDidMount()`.

Add this line inside the `render()` method of `index.js`
(or to the page-component that you want to invoke the script).

```
 const myScript = require('/pathTo/myScript.js')
```